# SearchBar does not work anymore after adding new objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cell, searchbar

I have integrated a searchBar in my application. And it worked fine. But after adding new elements to my tableView my searchBar does not work anymore. I get error messages in this code block:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; // Here i get: >Control reaches end of non void function<

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
if (searching)
{
    VerwaltungInformation *searchedFormel = [copyListOfFormularies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ; //Here i get: >Thread 1: Program received signal "SIGABRT"<

    cell.textLabel.text = searchedFormel.nameFormel;
}
else
{
NSDictionary *dictionaryCell = [listOfFormularies objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *arrayCell = [dictionaryCell objectForKey:@"Formel"];

VerwaltungInformation *cellValue = [arrayCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = cellValue.nameFormel;
}

return cell;
```

There seems to be a problem with the cellIdentifier - but I can not figure it out.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The warning `Control reaches end of non void function` comes when you wrapped up your `non void` method without returning an object. To figure out your problem, right click your mouse select `Structure` select `Re – Indent`. Now you can find out the structure of your code more easily and find out what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem might be earlier in the source file, above the method you posted.  Please try this:

**Step 1:**

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize ...

#if 0

// all of the code that precedes cellForRowAtIndexPath

#endif

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// and so on
```

Does the compiler still warn on the CellIdentifier?  My guess is no (though you'll probably see all kinds of errors below, related to symbols that you hid inside #if #endif).

**Step 2:**

Move the #if #endif pair to wrap methods one at a time in the file, method by method, starting with the method above the one you posted, until the CellIdentifier warning reappears.  When it does, you'll have found the source of the problem.

Comment: But i do not understand why the searchBar does not work anymore after adding new elements...
PS: I am new to objective-c...i can not really get what you mean...

Comment: Are you seeing a compiler error, like the comment in the code indicates, or are you able to run the app and it's just not behaving as you expect?